# Finding the differential of $y=(u+1)/(u-1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

I'm having trouble with differentials. I've been trying to learn about them online using great resources like [PatrickJMT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXIQKIj-NSo) but I'm having trouble finding examples for this kind or problem. I hate asking questions when I don't have any work to show but I'd like some help to get started.

**Find the differential of the following function:**
$$y = \frac{u+1}{u-1}$$

If someone could show me how to begin or link me to some information on the web, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{d}{du} \left ( \frac{u+1}{u-1}\right )=\frac{u-1-u-1}{(u-1)^2}=\frac{-2}{(u-1)^2}$$

$$dy=\frac{-2}{(u-1)^2} du$$

Comment: That's it? Just the derivative multiplied by du? Also, I got $\frac{-2}{(u-1)^2}$ for my derivative.

Comment: Yes,that's it.. You are right,I edited my answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your knowledge of differentials and derivatives. In most of the cases, you are taught about differentials via derivatives, and for functions of one variable you always get
$$
  dy(u) = y'(u)du.
$$
So you only have to compute the derivative $y'(u)$ e.g. via the derivative rule for fractions, and put $du$ from the right of that.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that (at the level of notation, at least) this is exactly what you do when you do a substitution for an integral (e.g. $f(y)dy=f(y(u))y'(u)du$.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: at least in my calculus course integrals were after differentials, so I'd rather don't confuse the OP just in case. But thanks for the suggestion, that's indeed one of the cases where we need to compute differentials rather than just derivatives (at least, on the formal level).

Comment: Yeah, I debated that point, and I meant it's worth pointing it out in comments---as you say, talking about integral analogies while doing differential calculus is a great view _after_ you've done both.